# Windows 10, how to stop cellular connection when wifi is available?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, internet

I have a windows 10 computer with a Wifi adapter and an USB 4G/LTE adapter.

The following scenario works:

- computer is connected to the internet via Wifi adapter
- Wifi network disappears
- computer automatically connects to LTE adapter to use internet

The opposite doesn't work:

- computer is connected to the internet via LTE adapter
- Wifi network appears

In this case the computer stays connected to the internet via the LTE adapter, even if it is supposed to automatically connect to the Wifi network.

Is there a way of solving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under advanced options in networking you can change the network order of preference. Highlight the USB 4g adapter and use the arrows to change order.

1. Navigate to *`Network and Sharing Center`*
2. Click *`Change adapter settings`*
3. Click the *`Advanced`* menu bar option and select *`Advanced Settings...`*
4. Select an adapter, then use the green arrows to change the order of precedence.

If your menu bar is not present like it is in the picture, simply press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the menu bar will appear.

[image: Advanced options in networking]

[image]